# Catching CTRL-C in PowerShell script

Tags: python, powershell, try-catch

I have created a shell script for both Bash and PowerShell that creates a python `venv`, enters it, installs requirements and runs the django migrations and server, like so:

```
cd my-proj
python -m virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate #### .\venv\Scripts\activate FOR PS
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
deactivate
cd ..
```

In Bash, when I stop the server with CTRL-C, the script will continue its execution, so it will correctly exit the `venv` and return to the previous folder.

But not in PowerShell. In PS it will stop the whole script. I would like to safely stop the `runserver` command by catching the CTRL-C. Is it possible?

Comment: In short: PowerShell allows you to perform _cleanup_ operations when a script is stopped via Ctrl-C, via the `finally` block of a `try` / `catch` / `finally` statement. That is, your script will _invariably terminate_, but
you can perform - limited - actions just before termination happens. See the linked duplicate for details.